# Retrieve a Link to Blogger Post based on Post ID using SyndicationItem

Tags: .net, blogger, atom-feed, syndication, syndication-feed

I'm trying to retrieve using Windows.Web.Syndication and a Blogger ATOM feed, the link of a post. 
The example I've seen from another feed reader (not using Blogger though) uses a SyndicationItem id to find the blog post link.

However, using this method, I get an Id in this format:

`/tag:blogger.com,1999:blog-5388280093621795916.post-2321273013867491101`

How can I access the original BlogPost URL using this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I haven't found the exact solution yet, but have found a workaround.

I've found that the Url can be reached in: (item is a SyndicationItem)

```
item.Links[4].Uri.AbsoluteUri;
```

In my case it was always on position number 4 of the Links array.